# Count of distinct values for different time zones

Tags: ravendb

I have a WorkItem doc with the properties defined below. There are 800K+ docs. I need to create a query that can quickly return the number of unique AccountIds for work items created for the API client's local day. API clients exist in different time zones. E.g. Client #1 may request the count for 01/10/22 (+1). Client #2 may request it for offset 0.

Client time zones are 0 to +3 and, if necessary, I could hard code each time zone in to the index definition.

What it the most efficient way to get the count for a given local date and offset? Without using an index then I can query the count by using the DotNet methods Select(m => m.AccountId), Distinct() & Count() but the query is slow. For efficiency then I wanted to do all of the work in a map/reduce index rather than just create an index on CreatedDateTimeUTC to filter the data down.

WorkItem document:

```
{
    "Id": "<Guid>",
    "CreatedDateTimeUTC": "<UTC Date Time>",
    "AccountId": "<Account Foreign Key>"
}
```

I'm using DotNet Core 6 and RavenDB 5.3 (Cluster on AWS)

Comment: What do you have in the index definition ?

Comment: There's no index because I really only wanted to use an M/R index so that that counts are done on the Raven server and the index is as small as possible. Obviously I could create an index on CreatedDateTimeUTC to speed up filtering the data and then call Select(), Distinct() & Count() but then the index would still be quite large.